# Android enabled preferences are grayed out

Tags: android, xml, layout, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Trying to create Android settings with preferences, which some of them open new Activity / custom Dialog with OnPreferenceClickListener. Everything is working fine, but the problem is that on real device, random preferences have gray colour like they are disabled. I am not able to find any pattern, why it is happening, but it only happens with clean Preference class. EditTextPreferences and others do not have this kind of problem. Here is example with some code.

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="@string/extra"
        app:key="annots">

        <Preference
            app:key="annot"
            app:title="@string/pref_annotation" />

        <Preference
            app:key="reset"
            app:title="@string/reset_extra" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="@string/app"
        app:key="version_android">

        <Preference
            app:key="about_app"
            app:title="@string/third_party"/>

        <Preference
            app:key="show_web"
            app:title="@string/website"/>

        <Preference
            app:key="pref_about_build"
            app:persistent="false"
            app:selectable="false"
            app:title="@string/build_version" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Whole Java code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Context context;
    public final static String GPS_DIS = "GPS_distance", GPS_TIME = "GPS_time", FILESIZE = "file_size", SAMPLING = "sampling_frequency", SAMPLING_WEAR = "sampling_frequency_wear";

    public final static  String FREE_MEMORY_PHONE_TO_SAVE = "free_memory_phone", FREE_MEMORY_WEAR_TO_SAVE = "free_memory_wear";
    public final static  String ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION_INTERVAL = "activity_recognition_refresh";
    private final static String AVAILABLE_MEMORY = "available_memory";
    public final static String AVAILABLE_MEMORY_WEAR = "available_memory_wear";


    private static int getDelay(int rate) {
        int delay = 0;
        switch (rate) {
            case SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_GAME:
                delay = 20000;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_UI:
                delay = 66667;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
                delay = 200000;
                break;
        }
        return delay;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.settings));
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, new PreferencesFragmentNew())
                .commit();

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main.class));
        return true;

    }

    public static class PreferencesFragmentNew extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        private ArrayList<String> setDigits = new ArrayList<String>(){{
            add(GPS_DIS);
            add(GPS_TIME);
            add(FILESIZE);
            add(ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION_INTERVAL);
            add(FREE_MEMORY_PHONE_TO_SAVE);
            add(FREE_MEMORY_WEAR_TO_SAVE);
        }};


        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey);
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));


            findPreference(SAMPLING).setSummary(getDelay(preferences.getInt(SAMPLING, 0)) +" μs");
            findPreference(SAMPLING).setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                DialogsOther.infoDialog(getContext(), DialogsOther.SAMPLING);
                return true;
            });


            findPreference(SAMPLING_WEAR).setSummary(getDelay(preferences.getInt(SAMPLING_WEAR, 2)) +" μs");
            findPreference(SAMPLING_WEAR).setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                DialogsOther.infoDialog(getContext(), DialogsOther.SAMPLING_WEAR);
                return true;
            });

            findPreference(AVAILABLE_MEMORY).setSummary(Memory.getFreeMemoryString());

            String memoryWear = preferences.getString(AVAILABLE_MEMORY, "");
            if(memoryWear.equals("")){
                findPreference(AVAILABLE_MEMORY_WEAR).setSummary(getContext().getString(R.string.unknown));
            }else{
                findPreference(AVAILABLE_MEMORY_WEAR).setSummary(getContext().getString(R.string.last_known)+" "+memoryWear+" MB");
            }

            for(String s : setDigits){
                EditTextPreference editTextPreference = findPreference(s);

                if(editTextPreference != null) {
                    editTextPreference.setOnBindEditTextListener(editText -> editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER));
                }

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                editTextPreference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(s, ""));
            }

            // resetting to default values - annotations
            findPreference("reset").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Main.RESET_STATS)));



            Preference pref = findPreference("activity_recognition_refresh");
            pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
                preference.setSummary(newValue + " s");
                return true;
            });

            findPreference("activity_recognition_about").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                DialogsOther.infoDialog(getContext(), R.string.title_activity_recognition,
                        R.string.about_activity_recognition_text).show();
                return true;
            });

            findPreference("about_app").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AboutApp.class));
                return true;
            });

            findPreference("annot").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AnnotationActivitySet.class));
                return true;
            });

            findPreference("show_web").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("..."));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            });
            findPreference("pref_about_build").setSummary(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main.class));
    }
}
```

The last one should be with gray color, but this happens and every time it is random:

[image]

I tried to change styles of preferences, their colours, set enabled programmatically, tried multiple phones with different versions of Android. Any suggestion / quick fix ? Or should I create own implementation.

Comment: Could your please share your Java/Kotlin code?

Comment: Update: this is not enough. I have worked with preferences quite a lot and haven't experienced this bug. So it's not normal. Share more, please. Whole class, if possible

Comment: Does it happen on a fresh install, or after you've done a "Clear Storage" via the app settings?

Comment: @greeble31 on the fresh install and the "Clear Storage" changes nothing